# Do any common computers use big endian encoding?

Tags: cpu-architecture, processor, endianness

I understand big endian and little endian. However, all the processors of all the computers accessible to me -- AMD, Intel, Broadcom -- are little endian. This leads me to wonder whether there are any common computers that use big endian. Can anyone provide examples?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Current_architectures

Comment: As I understand it, though, most bi-endian machines are typically run in little-endian mode these days — though I have no data to back that up.

Comment: Mainstream Intel and AMD are the same architecture (x86-64), not independent examples.  Many newer ISAs are little-endian, though, like ARM and AArch64 are normally operated in little-endian mode I think, although [the paper spec allows either for data](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102376/0100/Alignment-and-endianness) (instruction fetch which is always LE for AArch64.)

Comment: Also, nominated [endian] as a synonym of [endianness]: Anyone that wants to vote to confirm that, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/endianness/synonyms

Comment: This site is for specific programming problems/issues/howtos, not general discussion about computer technology.

Comment: Macs *used to be* big endian, when they used 68000 processors, before Apple switched to Intel (and now partially to ARM).

Comment: Basil, I know that "this site is for specific programming problems/issues/howtos, not ...", and I'm sorry I didn't really explain why this question is important. I have written some programs that are supposed to output text in the UTF-16BE encoding scheme, and I want to test them by outputting foreign language text and checking that it is correct. I can read multiple foreign languages, so if I can access a big endian computer I can easily test the output simply by reading it. Now, I can only pipe it to hexdump and read hex values. Alternatively, is there a BE emulator I can install?

Comment: Hopefully you realize that UTF-8 is the way to go, though.

Comment: Yes, thank you Erik. Most of my work is on UTF-8, and I really like it. However, I decided that I needed to be able to handle UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE if for no other reason than to go back and forth between them and UTF-8.

Comment: PowerPC and MIPS systems are often built to run in big-endian mode, IIRC.  Oh, apparently PowerPC Linux these days is little-endian, but AIX still runs in BE mode.

Answer (score 0):

The [LEON processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEON), commonly used in spacecraft applications, is [big-endian](http://microelectronics.esa.int/core/ipdoc/LEON_SystemC_UserManual.pdf).

Apparently, the LEON is a popular processor [to simulate](http://microelectronics.esa.int/core/ipdoc/LEON_SystemC_UserManual.pdf).